# What does number after function name reprsent in process stacktrace

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging

Below is gtsack output for one of the thread.

```
#0  0x00007fa6ba63edee in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fa6ba5f222d in _**L_lock_1598** () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fa6ba5f1fe6 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007fa6ba5f06a4 in ranged_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007fa6ba5f0d4b in __mktime_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

In this trace what is this 1598 after lock function. Does it signify any relevance and does this number changes after every call to lock function ?

Comment: learn about [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

Comment: It's simply a symbol, no the number will not change with the number of calls.

Comment: @RakibulHasan: Or don't, because it's a C symbol (from `libc.so.6`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of symbols from a library using `nm`, for example:

```
$ nm /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep _L_lock_ | cut -d' ' -f 3 | uniq | head
_L_lock_10
_L_lock_100
_L_lock_101
_L_lock_10182
_L_lock_1019
_L_lock_1023
_L_lock_10363
_L_lock_104
_L_lock_105
_L_lock_10507
```

(I count a total of 142 such distinct functions on my machine, although some appear multiple times for a total of 239 symbols)

Thus, no, this is "just" a fixed name. Those symbols are all `t`, meaning they are in the *text* section (the ELF section containing the code). The *text* section is not writable (in general), and thus they have been generated at compilation time.

There is also a total of 220 distinct `_L_unlock_100` functions (and the like).

---

You can find the code for libc on the web (they use git), jumping at the previous frame in [tzset.c#594](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/tzset.c;h=0d5420218537bf84d66a435428ff44d7293b40bf;hb=58423c7dbbea349041a4d96b1fdc51cdbc3a6ef1) we see a call to `__libc_lock_lock (tzset_lock);` which is a macro defined as:

```
#  define __libc_lock_lock(NAME) \
   ({ lll_lock (NAME, LLL_PRIVATE); 0; })
```

`lll_lock` is for low-level locks and the `LLL_PRIVATE` is used to tell that the symbol is private (not exported), thus we end up with a *generated name*, and that's where the number comes from.